# Bind dropdownlist to sql query in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using asp.net mvc. But I can't use Linq because the database is an externe database with more then 2000 tables in it. So I don' t have the db in the project but in mysql manager 2014. I query the data now with standard sql. Like this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index  (int? SelectedVestiging)       
{
    var query = "SELECT Code from [Verploegen TEST$Location]";
    Vestiging vestiging = await db.Vestigingen.SqlQuery(query, SelectedVestiging).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    if (vestiging == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(vestiging);
}
```

and  I have a model, like this:

```
public class Vestiging
{           
    [Key]
    public string Code { get; set; }               
}
```

The method is working. Because I see the data appears in vestiging. So that works. But now I want to have all the vestigingen in the view. There are five vestigingen.

I try it like this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Code", "All")
```

But then I will get this error:

> Additional information: The ViewData item that has the key 'Code' is of type 'System.String' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'.

I have it now like this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index  (int? SelectedVestiging)       
        {


            var query = "SELECT Code, Name from [Verploegen TEST$Location]";
            Vestiging vestiging = await db.Vestigingen.SqlQuery(query, SelectedVestiging).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

            if (vestiging == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            var allITems = db.Vestigingen
                 .Select(s => new SelectListItem { Value = s.Code, Text = s.Code }).ToList();
            ViewBag.WestVigs = allITems;

            return View(vestiging);



        }
```

and the view like this:

```
  @Html.DropDownList("Code", ViewBag.WestVigs as List<SelectListItem>);
```

But I get the error:

Invalid column name 'Code'.

Beschrijving: Er is een onverwerkte uitzondering opgetreden tijdens het uitvoeren van de huidige webaanvraag. Raadpleeg de stacktracering voor meer informatie over deze fout en de oorsprong ervan in de code.

Details van uitzondering: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'Code'.

```
Fout in bron: 


Regel 30:             }
Regel 31: 
Regel 32:             var allITems = db.Vestigingen
Regel 33:                  .Select(s => new SelectListItem { Value = s.Code, Text = s.Code }).ToList();
Regel 34:             ViewBag.WestVigs = allITems;
```

I still get an error:

```
StickerPrinterWeb.DAL.Verploegen_TEST_Location: : EntityType 'Verploegen_TEST_Location' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.

Locations: EntityType: EntitySet 'Locations' is based on type 'Verploegen_TEST_Location' that has no keys defined.
```

If I do it like this:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.[Verploegen TEST$Location]")]
    public partial class Verploegen_TEST_Location : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);

        private System.Data.Linq.Binary _timestamp;

        [Key]
        private string _Code;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `DropDownList` helper method expects you to pass the data needed to build the select options.

If you do not have a view model for the view, you may use ViewBag to send this information from your action method.

```
// your existing code goes here

var allITems = db.Vestigingen
                 .Select(s=>new SelectListItem { Value =s.Code, Text= s.Code}).ToList();
ViewBag.WestVigs=allITems; 

return View(vestiging);
```

and in your view,

```
@Html.DropDownList("WestVigs")
```

This will generate a SELECT element with name and id values set to "`WestVigs`". If you want the select element to have a different Id and name value, you can use another overload of `DropDownList` method.

```
@Html.DropDownList("Code", ViewBag.WestVigs as List<SelectListItem>);
```

This will generate a SELECT element with name and id values set to "`Code`"

Comment: HI Shju, thank you for your reply. I will check it thursday. Because Tomorrow I will have a free day. So I will let you know when I know more

Comment: HI Shyju, Can you maybe also have a look at this post: stackoverflow.com/questions/39245215/…

Comment: Hi, Edit the post

Comment: Your original question was about an error while populating the dropdown for all items from Vestigingen table and i posted an answer. Did you try that?  Did it work ? The you updated the post with a totally different error. You should not be doing that!. You should always post a new question wiith minimal relevant code. Otherwise it is hard for other people to understand your real issue and wont be able to help.

Comment: Yes ofcourse I tried that. But see my edit post. See my edit post. I added your code to my Index function. But I get an error that Code is not recognised

Comment: Which line are you getting the error ?. Also the edit you posted to the original question **"EntityType 'Verploegen_TEST_Location' has no key defined"** error is totally different than your original problem. I suggest you isolate your problem and try to fix it.  Take a moment read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)